# Context menu missing in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: contextmenu, visual-studio-2022, nswag

The project that I'm working on uses the Visual Studio (2022) extension 'Unchase OpenAPI (Swagger) Connected Services' to generate a C# controller. My colleague and I have both followed a [tutorial on Medium](https://medium.com/@unchase/how-to-generate-c-or-typescript-client-code-for-openapi-swagger-specification-d882d59e3b77) to setup this extension, and we have both installed version 1.7.1. However, in the solution explorer, I don't get the context menu item to update the connected service whereas my colleague does. The attached picture shows my environment (upper) and his (lower), and as can be readily seen, I'm missing an option.

So far I've tried to disable and enable the extension, restarting VS, and even restarting the PC.

Any idea why I cannot update the connected service?

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is a bug in Visual Studio 17.2.x. Workaround is to use NSwagStudio, but the template folder has (if you use it) is now relative to a temporary folder, not the one .nswag definition resides into.

https://bytemeta.vip/repo/unchase/Unchase.OpenAPI.Connectedservice/issues/70